# URL Redirect After Submitting form into an IFrame

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, wordpress

This is my first question at this platform feeling very excited about that:)

We have a .net script running into an IFrame embedded in wordpress page(s).

We use this for reservation. What we need is an URL redirect after form submit.

Can you please help us about this issue.

Regards

We already have a success message modal box appearing however we are not able to trigger that box. Thats why actually we are planning to redirect another page.

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you need. You want to redirect the iframe or the parent page?

Comment: Redirecting the iframe to another specific url once form submit completed, maybe right after success message modal box appears.

Comment: So why is the success page not doing a meta redirect?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, let me try to redefine my issue.

There is a reservation form running on a windows server and written with #c.
And we use this form into a seperate website running with wordpress. We want a redirection to an URL after that form submitted.